# php artisan schema:dump --prune causing error

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

When i use `php artisan schema:dump --prune`  it causes an error. I have mentioned the username in my database.php but it still gives an error. Can anyone help me?

```
Undefined variable: username

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:41
     37▕      */
     38▕     public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
     39▕     {
     40▕         [$username, $password] = [
  ➜  41▕             $config[$username] ?? null, $config[$password] ?? null,
     42▕         ];
     43▕ 
     44▕         try
     45▕         {

      +22 vendor frames 
  23  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Comment: Can you show us your `.env` database variables and your database config file ? **DO NOT SHARE YOUR REAL PASSWORD IF THIS IS PRODUCTION OR WHATERVER, CHANGE IT TO ANYTHING ELSE**

Answer (score 0):

> changed password and username

This is my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8888
DB_DATABASE=products
DB_USERNAME=username  
DB_PASSWORD=password
UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.lock
```

and this is my config

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```